# websphere 8.5.5 jaxws-rt: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl

Tags: java, web-services, jax-ws, websphere-8

i have to migrate my ear project from JBoss to WebSphere 8.5.5.

My webService (I use jax-ws) is correctly deployed and I can invoke it with no error, but, when I try to invoke an external webService, i get the following error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.sun.xml.ws.spi.ProviderImpl (initialization failure)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:176)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1564)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:36)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:95)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:82)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
```

jaxws-rt is in WEB-INF/lib directory, and I can use other classes from that library. I tried with a simple:

```
Class.forName("com.sun.xml.ws.Closeable").getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

Wich returns the expected path:

```
/opt/IBM/WAS8.5_1/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01_1/installedApps/svr04Cell02_1/MyEar.ear/MyWebService.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxws-rt-2.1.4.jar
```

This means that jaxws-rt is in my classpath. So, why can't I see ProviderImpl class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The platform can find the class - it just can't load it. It is _NoClassDefFoundError_ and not _ClassNotFoundException_. WAS 8.5.5 is a JAX-WS platform so perhaps there is some class-level incompatibility between the types in your WAR and those on your platform classpath.

Comment: Thank you for answer.To avoid platform and WAR conflict I already changed the classloader policy of Websphere to Parent_last.

Comment: It means there are multiple copies of that class available in your classpath. Fish out the duplicate and get rid of it